# Why encryptor and IV, key need to be generated from different AES instance?

Tags: c#, key, aes, initialization-vector

I'm looking at [AES MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aes.aspx) and the sample code for it. I noticed that IV and key used for creating the encrypto are obtained from another AES instance.

Meaning, for `ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key
, aesAlg.IV);`
the Key and IV are having the value of `myAes.Key`, `myAes.IV`.

Why is it ?

Comment: Because it's a poorly written sample? In a realistic scenario, you'd of course obtain the encryption key from some external location instead of using a randomly generated one.

Comment: @MichaelLiu while I agree the sample is poorly written, there are plenty of “realistic scenarios” where you would want to generate random AES keys (its maybe even arguably the norm), for example asymmetric/PKI scenarios. If you have a large payload to encrypt, you typically encrypt the payload with a random AES (or other fast symmetric cipher) key and then encrypt that key with (much slower) RSA or some other asymmetric cipher. This is basically how TLS/SSL works.